# Give examples for predicate function defined using only sums, products, sines

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry, polynomials, graph-theory

Fix a natural number $m$.

I have in mind a class of functions with these properties:

- The domain is a subset of $Z^{m + 2}$ (that is, there are $m + 2$ integer parameters), while the codomain is merely the set $\{0, 1\}$.
- The first parameter, $i$, is an integer such that $0 \leq i$.
- The second parameter, $j$, is an integer such that $i \lt j$.
- The rest of the parameters are just a vector from $Z^m$.
- A restriction on the kinds of expressions allowed for defining a function from this class: the only allowed operations are: addition, multiplication, exponentiation by a positive integer constant, sine, cosine. Introducing real number constants in the defining expression is allowed. Infinite sums and infinite products are not allowed.
- The function's result should depend on all of the function's parameters.
- To prevent uninteresting answers, a function is disallowed if there exists some $n$ such that for all $i$ greater than $n$ the function's result does not depend on $i$. Likewise for $j$ instead of $i$.

In case it interests anyone, the motivation for this question is using functions like these to generate undirected graph adjacency matrices.

I suggest giving example functions for at least $m = 1$ and $m = 2$.

If it makes an answer easier or possible, feel free to replace $Z$ with $N$ above.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed for reason of "*missing context*", since it *does* check several of the listed "*forms of context*". Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{m+2})=\sin^2 \big(\left(n_1+n_2+\dots+n_{m+2}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why. Just because a (very) simple answer exists doesn't make it wrong, or less of an answer.